# Python how to print a string every time a specific word is found within a string?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, list-comprehension

I am trying to get a output like this:

```
I dont want ANY spam
I dont want ANY spam
I dont want ANY spam
```

with this code:

```
wife = 'spam spam spam'
[print('i dont want ANY spam') for x in wife if 'spam' in wife]
```

but instead im getting:

```
I dont want ANY spam
I dont want ANY spam
I dont want ANY spam
I dont want ANY spam
I dont want ANY spam
I dont want ANY spam  
I dont want ANY spam
I dont want ANY spam
I dont want ANY spam
I dont want ANY spam
I dont want ANY spam
I dont want ANY spam
I dont want ANY spam
I dont want ANY spam
```

I only need it to print out every time it sees the word spam from the variable wife, how can i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for x in wife.split():
    if x == "spam":
        print ("I dont want ANY spam")
```

try this. you are iterating through each letter of `wife` instead of each word. `.split()` makes it iterate through each word.

Or you can try:

```
print ("I dont want ANY spam \n" * wife.count("spam"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could fix it by adding a `split()` in your `wife`

```
wife = 'spam spam spam'
[print('i dont want ANY spam') for x in wife.split(' ') if 'spam'==x]
```

Answer (score 2):

that happens because you are iterating a string, with which you will show by screen for each character of the string in this case `wife = 'spam spam spam' 
[print('i dont want ANY spam') for x in wife.split() if 'spam' == x]` this reduces the interactions to only three

although I do not understand why you use a list